# C# WebClient File downloads

Tags: c#, multithreading, download

I'm writing a download client, and it all works perfectly the first time. However on the second run, the bw_DownloadProgressChanged e.BytesReceived appears to be continuing the counting up, so it includes the bytes from the first download as well as the second download, and not resetting? How should I be starting a new download? Do I need to do some check and pass the current download to the DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler? Following is my cut down code. These downloads aren't happening at the same time, but the second waits for the first to complete.

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
try
{
    myWebClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(bw_DownloadDataCompleted);
    myWebClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_DownloadProgressChanged);

   Uri uri = new Uri(podcastTrack.PodcastDownloadAddress);
   myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, podcastTrack.PodcastTempLocation);                
}
catch (Exception exce)
{
    Console.Write("Error downlaoding page: \n\n" + exce.Message);
}

private void bw_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            (string)e.UserState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not Dispose() your Webclient just after calling DownloadFileAsync()

Comment: You're correct. I'd added it in to see if it fixed my issue, but alas not, and had forgotten to take it out again. Doesn't actually seem to make any difference.